# Boost spirit alternative operator doesn't fill all attribute values

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I read real numbers from a file, using boost spirit qi. I try to implement conditional parser, where input depends on the first character on the line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
using namespace std;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


struct  MyStruct {

   double r1, r2, r3, r4;
   double r5, r6, r7, r8;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
   MyStruct,

   (double, r1), (double, r2), (double, r3), (double, r4),
   (double, r5), (double, r6), (double, r7), (double, r8)
);

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
   string test =
      "A+1.000000000000e+00+2.000000000000e+00+3.000000000000e+00+4.000000000000e+00\r\n"
      "B+5.000000000000e+00+6.000000000000e+00+7.000000000000e+00+8.000000000000e+00\r\n";
   qi::rule<string::const_iterator> CRLF = qi::copy(qi::lit("\r\n"));
   qi::real_parser d19_12;

   MyStruct ms;
   qi::rule<string::const_iterator, MyStruct()> gr =

      qi::lit("A") >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> CRLF
      >> (
         (qi::lit('B') >> d19_12  >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> CRLF)
         |
         (qi::lit('C') >> d19_12  >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> +qi::lit('_') >> qi::attr(0.0) >> CRLF)
         )
      ;
   string::const_iterator f = test.cbegin();
   string::const_iterator e = test.cend();
   bool ret = qi::parse(f, e, gr, ms);

   return ret;
}
```

everything works as expected without 'C' alternative, but adding this alternative makes the parser skip the values, the result is

- ```
    ms  MyStruct
    r1  1.0000000000000000  double
    r2  2.0000000000000000  double
    r3  3.0000000000000000  double
    r4  4.0000000000000000  double
    r5  5.0000000000000000  double
    r6  -9.2559631349317831e+61 double
    r7  -9.2559631349317831e+61 double
    r8  -9.2559631349317831e+61 double
  ```

Expected result is:

- ```
    ms  MyStruct
    r1  1.0000000000000000  double
    r2  2.0000000000000000  double
    r3  3.0000000000000000  double
    r4  4.0000000000000000  double
    r5  5.0000000000000000  double
    r6  6.0000000000000000  double
    r7  7.0000000000000000  double
    r8  8.0000000000000000  double
  ```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug rules. So, simplifying the input to `"A+1+2+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n"` and wrapping the real parser into a rule, this is the debug output:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c6287011a73337a)**

```xml
<gr>
  <try>A+1+2+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8</try>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+1+2+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r</try>
    <success>+2+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[1]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+2+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[2]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+3+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[3]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+4\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[4]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <CRLF>
    <try>\r\nB+5+6+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>B+5+6+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </CRLF>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+5+6+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>+6+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[5]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+6+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>+7+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[6]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+7+8\r\n</try>
    <success>+8\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[7]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <d19_12>
    <try>+8\r\n</try>
    <success>\r\n</success>
    <attributes>[8]</attributes>
  </d19_12>
  <CRLF>
    <try>\r\n</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </CRLF>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4.27256e+180, 0, 0]]</attributes>
</gr>
Parsed: (1 2 3 4 5 4.27256e+180 0 0)
```

Indeed it confirms that all numbers were parsed. Why is attribute propagation not doing what you expect?

My guess is that it's attribute propagation trying to be accepting a little more than you expect. The problem is that your AST doesn't directly match the rule: the rule synthesizes

```
tup4 := tuple<double, double, double, double>
attribute := tuple<tup4, variant<tup4, tup4> >
```

In the Qi version this does get simplified to `tuple<tup4, tup4>` but your AST is actually like a `tup8`, which isn't the same. So when propagating, the rule just does what it thinks is the best option, which is assigning the first `tup4`. And then :shrug:

### Fixes

The simplest fix would be to make your AST match the rules. That might actually make most sense because more likely than not, the `"A"`, `"B"`, "`C`" have semantic meaning.

```
namespace Ast {
    struct A {
        double r1, r2, r3, r4;
    };
    struct BC {
        double r5, r6, r7, r8;
    };
    struct MyStruct {
        A  a;
        BC bc;
    };

    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace Ast
```

Adapting them:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::A, r1, r2, r3, r4)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::BC, r5, r6, r7, r8)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::MyStruct, a, bc)
```

> Note that, without further changes, this just confirms that *automatic* attribute propagation is a heuristics--based: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d954d13eec843f09): `Parsed: ((1 0 0 0) (2 0 0 0))` (oops)

Making the rules match that structure:

```
qi::rule<It>         CRLF   = "\r\n";
qi::rule<It, double> d19_12 = qi::double_;

qi::rule<It, Ast::A()>  A  = "A" >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12; //
qi::rule<It, Ast::BC()> BC =                                              //
    'B' >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 |                         //
    'C' >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> +qi::lit('_') >> qi::attr(0.0);

qi::rule<It, Ast::MyStruct()> gr = A >> CRLF >> BC >> CRLF;
```

Now it all works: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c7e005bba142221)

Prints

```
Parsed: ((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8))
```

### Outside The Box

A lot of this seems XY problem to me. A struct with 8 non-descript numbers that can have varying meanings seems... not what you actually need.

Also, that B/C distinction seems to suggest you really want an "optional number" rule:

```
rule<It>         CRLF   = "\r\n";
rule<It, double()> d19_12 = raw[ //
    double_[_val = _1] |         //
    omit[+char_("_")]            //
][_pass = px::size(_1) == 19];

rule<It, Ast::Tup4()> Tup4 =
    omit[char_("ABC")] >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12;
```

*Note how `omit[char_("ABC")]` directly reflects my intuition that you're throwing away semantic information in your model.*

Now the grammar becomes

```
rule<It, Ast::MyStruct()> gr = Tup4 >> CRLF >> Tup4 >> CRLF;
```

And indeed, it parses the full input: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e2dc84655595949)

```
Parsed: ((1.0001 2.0002 3.0003 4.0004) (5.0005 6.0006 7.0007 8.0008))
```

### Simplify! Containers

In fact, I suspect that you might even be better served with something like:

```
namespace Ast {
    using Reals = boost::container::static_vector<double, 8>;
} // namespace Ast
```

The fun fact is that containers **do** enjoy more flexible attribute propagation (with a new [caveat](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html)). You can have something straight-forward as:

```
qi::rule<It, Ast::Reals(char const*)> Line =
    qi::omit[qi::char_(_r1)] >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12;

qi::rule<It, Ast::Reals()> gr = //
    Line(+"A") >> CRLF >> Line(+"BC") >> CRLF;
```

Let me conclude with a live example of such: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ooKv5KP9z)¹**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace Ast {
    using Reals = boost::container::static_vector<double, 8>;
} // namespace Ast

int main()
{
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    using namespace qi::labels;

    qi::rule<It>         CRLF   = "\r\n";
    qi::rule<It, double()> d19_12 = qi::raw[ //
        qi::double_[_val = _1] |             //
        qi::omit[+qi::char_("_")]            //
    ][_pass = px::size(_1) == 19];

    qi::rule<It, Ast::Reals(char const*)> Line =
        qi::omit[qi::char_(_r1)] >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12 >> d19_12;

    qi::rule<It, Ast::Reals()> gr = //
        Line(+"A") >> CRLF >> Line(+"BC") >> CRLF;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((gr)(Line)(d19_12)(CRLF))

    for (std::string const test : {
             "A+1.000100000000e+00+2.000200000000e+00+3.000300000000e+00+4.000400000000e+00\r\n"
             "B+5.000500000000e+00+6.000600000000e+00+7.000700000000e+00+8.000800000000e+00\r\n",
             "A+1.000100000000e+00+2.000200000000e+00+3.000300000000e+00+4.000400000000e+00\r\n"
             "C+5.000500000000e+00+6.000600000000e+00+7.000700000000e+00___________________\r\n",
         }) {
        It f = test.cbegin(), e = test.cend();

        Ast::Reals data;
        if (parse(f, e, gr, data)) {
            fmt::print("Parsed: {}\n", data);
        } else {
            fmt::print("Failed\n");
        }

        if (f != e) {
            std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f, e))
                      << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: {1.0001, 2.0002, 3.0003, 4.0004, 5.0005, 6.0006, 7.0007, 8.0008}
Parsed: {1.0001, 2.0002, 3.0003, 4.0004, 5.0005, 6.0006, 7.0007, 0}
```

---

¹ I lazed out on the output formatting, using libfmt instead of writing my vector printing cruft again; Coliru doesn't have libfmt (or c++23) yet

Comment: Thank you, you helped me again, I didn't notice, that with alternative operator I replaced the part of attribute vector to another vector and it broke everything. The letters ABC, in fact, were conditions where some numbers can be missed or replaced. I just try to make examples as smaller as possible. What I took as example is a part of a larger struct and the rule is a part of larger grammar. So, if I want to keep the struct as is and add some variability to the grammar I have to parse to temporary structs or expose part of the big struct as a vector of suitable attributes

Comment: and you are right, all numbers are successfully parsed, in my case, but the last ones with attribute of unused type, now I see why

Comment: When I said "X# problem" I meant that there are probably much more elegant ways to deal with the _eventual task_ that you're trying to solve. The fact that we don't **know** what that task is makes it so our help is necessarily sub-optimal, and potentially misguiding. Perhaps we can start a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/) if you can share more of the background and actual task at hand, instead of the existing approaches or ideas?